# Display Confetti effect only in the lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have created a lightning component, which is added to the lead record. This component is used to show the Confetti effect on the lead-based on certain conditions.

The code for the confetti, I have taken is from [this](https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2019/07/19/add-confetti-effect-to-lightning-components-and-flows/) blog.

Currently, the confetti effect is applicable to the whole page, instead, I want it to display only on the custom lightning component.

How can I restrict it to only the lighting component?

Comment: In the blog mentioned in your question, `canvasConfetti` implements the functionality you are looking for. Does that now work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works for me, but currently, the effect is on the whole page. but I want it in only my lightning component.

Comment: `canvasConfetti` does implement this functionality for a specific section of the page and ***not on the whole page*** (to be precise, it has the effect within the height & width of the canvas element declared in the component HTML).